# String to float maintaining decimal places

Tags: solidity, string, uint256

I've seen some thread already however I haven't found anywhere a way of converting a string number to float number and maintaining the decimals.

ie

```
"27.546" to 27.546
```

Comment: "uint number and maintaining the decimals"? Seriously??? Do you understand the meaning of "int" in "uint"?

Comment: you are right. String to float number.

Comment: Shift the decimal point position to the right and use integer arithmetic

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MadJackal. Can you show a quick example?

Comment: There are no floating-point types in Solidity. You need to do all the floating-point arithmetic on the off-chain side (for example, in a web3.js script), and use only integers when you interact with the on-chain (i.e., when you pass input to contract functions).

Comment: Understood. So in my case in the contract I should pass 27546, right? And if so wouldn't that change the value of my original price?

Comment: Imagine that you are calculating not in dollars, but in cents. The principle is the same. For a more detailed example, is need to know the essence of your calculations.

Comment: @MadJackal you are right! That wasn't so difficult after all.